# Cross compile uClibc can't find some linux kernel header

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, uclibc

Here is a quick description followed by the details. 
I try to cross compile uClibc for ARM EABI. I have my own compiled Linux Kernel and I extracted the header files. I placed it in a folder. In uClibc ".config" file I have the variable KERNEL_HEADERS= set to the proper folder. In fact, during compilation the headers are found to a certain point. Here is an example where it is found and breaks mid way: compiling file

"libc/inet/if_index.c"

That file will generate a series on chained includes in each file as follow:

"libc/inet/netlinkaccess.h"   (this does a #include of following linux header)

"kernel_hdr/linux/rtnetlink.h"  (this one #include the next one)

"kernel_hdr/linux/netlink.h"  (this one #include for the next one)

"kernel_hdr/linux/kernel.h"   (this one tries and fails #include  )

This is that `#include <asm/types.h>` that breaks the chain. It's the first one that is not a `#include <linux/xxx.h>` but `<asm/xxx.h>`. The file asm/types.h exist but is not found. No warnings no error. It just says

" error: unknown type name '__kernel_long_t'"

That type is defined in the broken series of includes. I even put some big syntax error to see if it reads it. Nope! I thought there is a problem with the handling a the Kernel header folder structure recognition. I tried to merge the kernel header with the uClibc regular headers (...uClibc/include/). No matter how I set KERNEL_HEADERS= (empty or full path) in the .config file, I get the exact same behaviour. I have no clue how to solve this one.

Here are more details on my setup:

workstation : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

uClibc is the latest version from GIT downloaded 3 days ago

Linux Kernel version 4.9.0 coming from Xilinx git. (I work on Zynq dual Cortex A9)

GCC ARM EABI is coming from Xilinx SDK 2017.1.

With that toolchain, I successfully compiled a custom FSBL (first stage boot loader), a custom Linux Kernel (I skip u-boot, FSBL loads kernel straight), device tree and package the whole thing, it runs  on the hardware up to rootfs.  I'm now building a custom rootfs (busybox successful, dropbear etc. ) the only failing is this uClibc that I can't compile because it does not find some of the includes inside of some header files although they exist.

To build uClibc,  I use from the uClibc folder:

```
make menuconfig

make clean

make CROSS=arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

How can I make uClibc build find all the kernel header files?

Comment: I haven't bothered to build individual components in a decade now that there are tools such as crosstool-NG and Buildroot. Since the toolchain and C library and kernel are inter-related, it makes sense to build them together as a set.

Comment: Read what @sawdust wrote, I would suggest the same.

Comment: I first tried Yocto. I can build distribution "easily". When I wanted to customize for Xilinx Zynq, I introduced the Xilinx meta-layers. It becames a real nightmare. There are still things not working. Then, I resorted to go back to Xilinx's Petalinux (had painful experience with it 2 years ago). Not working for customized hardware)... Petalinux = bloody nightmare. Went to the good old "git clone source + make menuconfig". Everything's  working except a few packages for roots (uClibc). And I got rid of u-boot. I'm trying Buildroot. I don't know crosstool-NG but I will look at it for sure.

Comment: *"I first tried Yocto. ... It becames a real nightmare."* -- Nobody suggested Yocto.  Using Buildroot is just like building the Linux kernel.  First `make <board_def_config>`, then customize with `make menuconfig`, and finally `make`.  Repeat last two steps if necessary.  crosstool-NG is just for a toolchain.  I use it to build a toolchain that is "external" to Buildroot.  Otherwise you can let Buildroot build a toolchain for you.